# Reduce Database size

Tags: database, entry-versions

I would like to reduce the size of a site's database. The reasons are as follows:

- To speed up the syncing process from live to local
- To hopefully speed up sql query execution time (an experiment)

I have many sections and hundreds upon hundreds of entries, all with versioning enabled. My question is, is there a way to 'trim the fat', or to put it better perhaps remove stale old version types (perhaps just keep the 5 most revisions for each entry)?

Thanks in advance for you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're specifically looking to trim the `entryversions` table, there is a [plugin](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/10675/57) that can automate the process for you.

Beyond that, you can safely truncate these tables as well when moving between environments:

```
assetindexdata
assettransformindex
sessions
templatecaches
templatecachecriteria
templatecacheelements
```